# react-native metro throws error in traverseDependency, can package-lock.json be the reason?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, react-navigation

The error I get is described [here on github](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/357) in detail. Basically the metro bundler fails with the following error:

*error: bundling failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
at resolveDependencies (C:\Apps\MyProject\rnw\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:370:18)
at C:\Apps\MyProject\rnw\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:188:33
at Generator.next ()
at step (C:\Apps\MyProject\rnw\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:298:30)
at C:\Apps\MyProject\rnw\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:309:15
at 
DELTA [android, dev] ....../index.js ▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 14.7% (221/612), failed.*

This error message does not help me much, as I am not deep into how the metro bundler works.

So I checked recent changes I did in the code, e.g. I added the following to my project:

```
"react-native-tab-view": "^1.3.2",
```

After that, I have a weird change in package-lock.json. It seems react-native-tab-view was already existing there, I guess because it is a dependency of another project I imported before. Here is the first change in package-lock.json:

[image: First Change package-lock.json]

Ok so whatever, this looks still ok to me. What is weird is the second change I see:

[image: Second change in package-lock.json]

Wait, what? A dependency to react-native-tab-view was added to react-navigation-deprecated-tab-navigator with the old version number 0.0.77? That looks strange, at least for me.

Can somebody help me out here - is this change normal, or can this be the reason why metro bundler fails?

Any input appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the issue by emptying the C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp folder.

Answer (score 4):

No Need to Empty whole folder
I solved the issue by deleting only one folder  **metro-cache**

Path : C:\Users\Harsh1311\AppData\Local\Temp